# Regex that starts with letter, contains one uppercase/one lowercase letter, one number and no special characters & min 8 characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to write a regex that:

- starts with a letter
- contains one uppercase and one lowercase letter
- contains one number
- does not allow special characters
- minimum 8 characters

So far I have the upper/lowercase conditions, the number and minimum character requirements set with the following regex:

```
 /^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/
```

My best guess at resolving the `starts with a letter` and `does not allow special characters` requirements are below. This regex seems to evaluate all input to `false`:

```
/^[a-zA-Z](?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/
```

Comment: 2 regex giants have posted their answers and I wonder who will win ...

Comment: This is an FAQ. You have not done your homework.

Comment: Can you provide a link? I searched SO for the problem specified in my post and did not find an adequate answer.

Comment: This is more like a logical issue here, not any "FAQ". Besides, the "homework" was done well, since the efforts and the description of what is not working are provided. Not a dupe by all means.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the lookaheads after `^` and put `[a-zA-Z]` right after them and quantify the rest with `{7,}`:

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}$
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fGk1AC/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=.*?[a-z])` - at least 1 lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*?[A-Z])` - at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*?[0-9])` - at least 1 ASCII digit
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}` - 7 or more ASCII letters or digits (`\w` also allows `_`)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This is perfect. I don't want to allow the underscore character, however. Is there a way to exclude that as well?

Comment: Nevermind, I see. Your first answer (minus the `\w`) doesn't allow the underscore

Comment: Ok, I removed the `\w` related part. I thought it could be useful.